# ORA-00600: internal error code when compiling function returning Pipelined

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-package

I have a package specification with code like below

```
CURSOR my_cur   IS      
select ...;   

TYPE mytype IS TABLE OF my_cur%ROWTYPE;   

FUNCTION myfun       
RETURN mytype  PIPELINED;
```

when I try to compile the package specificaiton, I get the following error:

> **ORA-00600**: internal error code, arguments: [psdmsc.c: spawned type
>   invalid], [0x1ED93D3C10], [3], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []

The interesting part is that the body of the package containing this  function compiles just fine.

I thought the resultset might cause problems but the query in my cursor returns at most 1 row

Comment: and without pipelined function the spec compiles without any errors?

Comment: yes. And if I put both the function spec and body into the package body all compiles well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an issue - in my cursor query one of the aliases was a reserved keyword. Using escape characters did not prevent it from being seen as a reserved keyword. The interesting thing was that query worked fine on its own but prevented the function from compiling

Answer (score 1):

This issue might be met within these version range for DB.

The error might arise due to the compiling a pipelined function returning a PL/SQL table of `my_cur%ROWTYPE` when the following situations met :

- the cursor[ or table] `my_cur` referenced in `my_cur%ROWTYPE` is owned by a
  different schema than the function
- there is another function in another schema having the same name as
  the failing function
- this `other function` refers to the same cursor[ or table] as the failing function,
- this `other function` is either in the same schema as the cursor[ or table] or in a different one.

For a workaround, connect to sys [or system], and check out the objects with invalid status by

```
SQL> SELECT owner,object_name,status
  FROM dba_objects
 WHERE status = 'INVALID'
   AND object_type = 'TYPE'
   AND object_name LIKE 'SYS_PLSQL_%' 

OWNER OBJECT_NAME          STATUS
----- -------------------- --------
USER1 SYS_PLSQL_12345_2_1  INVALID
```

then compile the type returned

```
SQL> alter type USER1.SYS_PLSQL_12345_2_1 compile;
SQL> show error
```

might return PLS-00201 for another type such as

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
0/0 PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
1/44 PLS-00201: identifier 'USER2.SYS_PLSQL_12346_7_1' must be declared
```

then grant the execute privilege to the owner of the invalid type

```
SQL> grant execute on USER2.SYS_PLSQL_12346_7_1 to USER1;
```

then recompile the invalid type

```
SQL> alter type USER1.SYS_PLSQL_12345_2_1 compile;
SQL> show error
```

and recheck out the objects with invalid status by the above query, if returns no row, 
then the concerned package can safely be compiled

```
SQL> alter package USER1.mypackage compile;
```

Ref. Doc ID 1185303.1 from Oracle Support

Comment: I do not have access to dba_objects. Also I did find that article you are mentioning and none of the cases listed fit here.

Comment: @CodingDuchess The Document tells us that *After compiling the invalid type, the error
PLS-00201 is raised. This is the issue described in Bug 8425548 ORA-00600 [PSDMSC.C SPAWNED TYPE INVALID] WHILE COMPILE PACKAGE*